# Need to create ArrayList method that fills with a Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a method that takes input from a data file (double type) using scanner and fills the Arraylist(double). I have a scanner created in my main class. I'm not sure how to get this to work correctly, though I feel like I'm almost there.

This is my main and public class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog11{

public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    readArr(inFile);
}
```

Here is my method

```
public static double[] readArr(Scanner inFile){

    ArrayList <Double> examList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
        input.add(inFile.nextDouble());
    }

    return examList;

}
```

here are the two errors left

```
./Prog11.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            input.add(inFile.nextDouble());
            ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Prog11


./Prog11.java:36: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Double> cannot be 
converted to double[]
return examList;
```

Comment: You haven’t declared `input` anywhere. The second one you’re returning an `arraylist`, but method signature is looking to return an `array`

Comment: Just changed input to examList, so thats working!!

Comment: And change the method signature to an `arrayList` and you’re sorted.

Comment: Would that mean to change public static double to public static ArrayList

Comment: `public static ArrayList<Double> readArr...`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. One, you need to return a list, not an array; Two, your variable is `inFile` not `input`.

```
public static List<Double> readList(Scanner inFile){
    List<Double> examList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
        inFile.add(inFile.nextDouble());
    }

    return examList;

}
```

If you absolutely have to return an array, then use

```
public static double[] readList(Scanner inFile) {
    List<Double> examList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
        inFile.add(inFile.nextDouble());
    }
    double[] arr = new double[examList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < examList.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = examList.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you dont return that was expected, if you said that you are going `double[]` and in the method you return an `arrayList<Double>` so you need to decide what are you retrurning.

```
public static ArrayList <Double> readArr(Scanner inFile){
ArrayList <Double> examList = new ArrayList<Double>();

while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){
     input.add(inFile.nextDouble());
 }

 return examList;

 }
```

Comment: Now im getting just one error, after realizing input.add should be examList.add, im left with this error                                   
    ./Prog11.java:36: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Double> cannot be converted to double[]
return (examList);

Comment: Whilst I won’t downvote this, you only answer half the problem.

Comment: OH! i get it now, I need to return an arrayList<Double>, is the correct notation  -- return arrayList<Double> examList;

Comment: Where did you get the `input` variable from? This code will not work as `input` does not exist. This is a half solution at best.